# laravel - Move app to another server, blank page and artisan error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I need to move app in laravel from web server to local sever (I trying on XAMPP). I moved all files, database and in files I changed URI in:
**/index.php**

```
<? header("Location: http://localhost/public"); ?>
```

but I get errors in:

- On http://localhost/ I have blank page
- On http://localhost/public and every another route I getting error: http://pastebin.com/zUFqS8ET
- When I use `php artisan` or another commands I getting error:

  `[ErrorException]
   Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT`

I forgot about somethink?

**EDIT:**
Ok, I downgrade my PHP to 5.6.* but artisan still not working - same error, what's the problem?

**EDIT 2:**
Here is logs - problem is in SMF but I don't know why ...
http://pastebin.com/HZQ7CZeg

Comment: Did you change .env to suit the new situation?

Comment: Sure, I replace to my local config

Comment: You sure your localhost has the same PHP version as the old web server?  when you google that error it seems to be related to php 7

Comment: True, I forgot about that. I'll try to change PHP version to lower and I'll write here.

Comment: Also did you try enabling debug in the app : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors

and looking in the php / apache error logs?

Comment: Ok, I downgrade my PHP to 5.6.* but artisan still not working - same error, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is obvious. But, have you run PHP composer install? And as a basic test you can create an empty laravel project to test your computer's configuration. If it works then you know its something in your project you need to update.

[Laravel installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installation)

Comment: I can't install and update because it's getting this error: http://prntscr.com/bydzcz